# I have a problem in map function in React even don't have any error in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-redux

I am having issue in map function. I am trying to loop inside `<li></li>` through map. I am using value of `useSelect` from Redux-Toolkit and it's not throwing any error in console, but it's not iterating.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import CreateNotes from '../CreateNotes/CreateNotes'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function Notes() {
    const [mapValue, setMapValue] = useState([])

    const value = useSelector((state) => state.clickToShow.clickValue || [])

    console.log('this is from value:', value);

    return (
        <div className='w-[calc(100%-4rem)] ml-16  mt-24'>
            <CreateNotes />
            <div className='w-full h-32 my-6 border border-black flex flex-col items-center   '>
                <ul>
                    <li>test li</li>
                    {value && value.map((each)=>{
                        <li key={each.id}>{each.text}</li>
                    })}
                    <li>test last</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Notes
```

I have tried so many time, but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: It's iterating (if there are any elements in `value`), but the callback of your `map` doesn't return anything